# Safari 100% Width and Height

Tags: html, css, safari, height, zurb-foundation-6

So on the following site I've been developing - http://exoticzoo.lspoor.co.uk

The 'Have you seen us' section is a full width block with two columns, right with an image and left with text content.

For desktop I apply the image as a background and use background size cover and on mobile I simply use an image tag. My problem is on Safari that the background image doesn't work, I am using a width and height of 100% to fill that block but it appears Safari doesn't respect this. The site is actually built on Foundation 6 so I have tried using the Foundation Equalizer plugin to set the height but this appears to also fail. Is there any solution for this?

It works fine on any other browsers (e.g. Chrome)

Comment: This can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33636796/chrome-safari-not-filling-100-height-of-flex-parent

Answer (score 0):

You can use Viewport Units. Check out quick tutorial video, you'll love it! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=du6gnsImsLU